# Div height 100% not working - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for a grid system, I am having trouble making a col-6 have a height:100%, in order to vertically align some text inside it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 center ">
        <img alt=" " class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/sitewide/mainpageeconomy.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 fillme">
        <p>We also offer a 30 foot Grady White center console. She's more of a hardcore no frills fishing vessel, we normally take her 20 to 40 miles offshore for bottom fishing and trolling for game fish up to 4 anglers.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

the fillme class has a height and min height of 100%

Help is much appreciated.

Update - I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.dnwebdev.com/index.php/2015/07/29/my-bootstrap-tool-belt-equal-height-columns/) about this! definitely a nice piece of code to have handy.

Comment: Lochemage's answer below is correct. If you want `.fillme` to be the height of it's parent, you'll need to set a height on that parent. Adding `.row { height: 500px;}` will fix that part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this

```
.col-lg-6 {    
    width: 49% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

Comment: Incredible, thank you! Edit: Can you explain it a little? This should be a built in class to bootstrap! Good job!!

Comment: It's a shame you can't use .col-lg-6 as a "only on large screens", it's treated like a class ;)

Comment: Well with display inline-block and vertical-align middle you will have both .col-lg-6 divs inside the parent .row be aligned in the middle. The height of the parent will be taken from the element with the bigger height, in your case the image, and the textual div will be vertical aligned in the available space of the parent. We remove the float that is added by bootstrap because floated elements can't be vertical aligned.

Answer (score 1):

A percentage height or width assigned to an element will only make it a percentage size of its parent element, not the entire browser window.  If the parent doesn't have a height or width assigned to it, child elements with a percentage value have no effect.

Make sure the parent `div` element also contains a height value.

EDIT:

In your case, you can use position magic to achieve the result you want:

CSS:

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: relative;
}

.fillmeright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.fillmeleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Just replace the `fillme` class with the appropriate `fillmeright` or `fillmeleft`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I set a height I would have to adjust with media queries, would it be better to use js/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Give your parent row '.fillme' class, remove from col-lg-6 that class and have it like this:

```
.fillme{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

cheers, k